# BrowserLink in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, browser-link

Upgrading .Net Core 2.2 to .Net Core 3.0 my browser link is become not working, anyone know how to troubleshoot.
Performing the edit cshtml and refresh the browser it didn't reflect the changes.

Comment: I found a thread about it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/793030/browserlink-not-updating-page-on-save.html. I just updated to Visual Studio 16.4.0 and the problem still there with .NET Core 3.1. :-/

Comment: T___T this make the developing process very tedious and slow now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workaround [suggested here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/16837) helps:

- Add the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`
- Change `services.AddControllersWithViews();` by `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`
- After saving you need to click the Browser Link refresh button `Ctrl+Alt+Enter` but it's better than restarting the application

  [image]

Comment: Didnt work for .NET 5 Razor Pages and Firefox.